# Session or Token auth for Backend and two Frontend apps at different locations

Tags: django, authentication, session, jwt

I have a Django App which acts backend and some endpoint built with Django REST Framework. There are 2 pieces of frontend interacting with my Django app. I have not implemented auth/login to my app. But before i do that, i have few questions to ask.
Below is a picture of the system.

[image: [IMG]]

`React_user` is a React app **BUT** `React_admin` is a low-code app like Retool (drag & drop components to make UI connected via REST API to backend) which is **sitting at differnt servers** i.e physically seperated at differnt locations

- `React_user` is the app for customer where they should be able to login with username and password created by `React_admin`
- `React_admin` is the on who creates customers, create username, password for each customer. Think of this as walk-in account creation as there is no sign-up for customers.
- So, `React_admin` creates customer credentials from the React app managed by admin, again is sitting at differnt server. For simplicity, let's say `React_admin` is hosted at the office itself.
- To create users, i'm using basic django `Users` model comes out of the box.So, to create a user, there is a an endpoint made with Django REST Framwork. The endpoint is `https://mapp.com/rest/create_user` which expects a `POST` request from `React_admin` with below information:

```
 {
    "username": "basil",
    "email": "mail@basil.com",
    "password": "Myp4passw0rd",
    "unique_username" "b4silpark"
 }
```

When `rest/create_user` gets this `POST` request, it simply creates that user by importing standard `Users` model in django.
It should be also noted that, for each user beign created, our app creates a subdomain under their username. Here a new subdomain is created as `b4silpark.mapp.com`.

You can immediatly notice that i donot authenticate `React_admin`. I'm not sure whether it's the `React_admin` itself sending the POST request. Technically anyone could send a POST to this endpoint to create a user.Before we move futher, let's make few things clear.

- `React_admin` is hosted at: `44.12.12.12`
- `Django app` is hosted at: `45.13.13.13` (same as React_admin)
- `React_user` hosted at `45.13.13.13` (same as Django app)

Again, as i mentioned in the app, there is no auth handled in `Django` app.

Question: Which auth should i use here? Session Auth or Token based auth like JWT.? Since we know the auth must be handled from differnt origins and the fact that for each user, there is a differnt subdomain which techically means each user comes from a differnt host? As noted, `React_admin` is interacting from a differnt server/IP. Is it good to use Session based auth everywhere? Again, `React_admin` does not have a login or stuff, it's a low-code platform itself.I was thinking if needed, i could copy a session of active user and include that cookie in every API request. Does this work? Is it a good idea?

Comment: Good question, It's pity to see no answer on it. So how did you make it in the end?

Comment: For `React_admin`, i have used token auth in [token auth](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication) and users using Django app uses session